# Can I show a window while printing?

Tags: macos, cocoa, printing, nsview

I have a subclass of `NSView` used only for printing, and it does some fairly complicated stuff while printing, which may result in a progress dialog appearing.  The problem is that the progress dialog draws into the printout rather than onto the screen.

I tried bracketing places that might draw to a window with `[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState]` and `[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];`, and that didn't work.

I also tried

```
[self unlockFocus];
[self stuffThatMightDrawAWindow];
[self lockFocus];
```

and that didn't work.  In fact I found that just after the `unlockFocus`, `[NSView focusView]` still points to my printing view, as if the `unlockFocus` didn't actually do anything.

I suppose I should attempt to reorganize my code so that only drawing to the printout happens in my printing view's `drawRect:` method, but I'm curious as to whether that's the only solution.

---

I tried refactoring to do all the content preparation in the `rectForPage:` method, the first place where I know the page number.  Now the printout looks OK, but if I run a simple modal `NSAlert` during `rectForPage:`, the alert is blank except for the button:

[image: white alert]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an [old (2001) post by Erik M. Buck](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/43077-text-editor.html#38818) saying:

> While an NSView is printing, its connection to the Window Server is replaced
>   by a connection to the print job output. Sometimes the NSView needs to
>   communicate briefly with the Window Server while printing; for example, it
>   may need to read some data stored only on the Window Server, or open an
>   attention panel to alert the user of a problem. In these cases, it can
>   temporarily swap in the NSApplication object's display context to restore
>   access to the application's Window Server state and to the screen. When
>   finished, the view object restores the print operation's context to continue
>   generating its image.

So, the solution was

```
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext: [NSApp context]];
[self stuffThatShowsDialogsInsteadOfPrinting];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

It's that second line, with `[NSApp context]`, that I would never have thought of without a hint.